# Opening ggplot2 along with other packages

Tags: r, installation

I have the following code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Nicholas/Desktop/Answers")
sessionsimpressions<-read.csv('impressionsandsessions.csv')
library(ggplot2)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =     vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

I tried .libPaths() and this is what came up:

```
[1] "C:/Users/Nicholas/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"
```

I know it has to do something with my setup. I even uninstalled RStudio and R, that still didn't work. If anyone can help that would be great because currently I can't do any work with R.

I have looked at other solutions such as seeing if Rcpp is in both libraries but that didn't work.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: It's only ggplot2 which is weird. I can open library(stats), library(dygraphs), etc. Just can't open ggplot2

Comment: ggplot2 imports dplyr which imports Rcpp, see `available.packages()["ggplot2", "Imports"]`

Comment: If the error message says you don't have **Rcpp**, why not just `install.packages("Rcpp")`?

Comment: @bunk can you post this in an answer format so that I can approve it. That worked, thanks!

Comment: I installed Rcpp, it didn't work before uninstalling it for some reason. But good to go